# sql convert date format not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I can not convert field run_date on sysjobhistory table from yyyymmdd to mmddyyyy.

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10),run_date),101) as Date from sysjobhistory
```

Please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: Is Run_Date a date/datetime data type or VARCHAR?

Comment: datetime   data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date type does not have `yyyymmdd` nor `mmddyyyy`. This type only valid for string (as varchar, nvarchar). Plus, you have extra `)` after rundate.

The correct one should be:

`select CONVERT(varchar(10),run_date,101) from sysjobhistory`

where `101` is style argument: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @dt date ='20161025'
select @dt,CONVERT(varchar(15),@dt,101)
```

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/abd0a/2)

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be: CONVERT (varchar(10), run_date, 101). What I am trying to say is that you have an extra parenthesis after run_date.

Comment: select CONVERT(varchar(10),run_date,101) as Date from sysjobhistory still not convert

Comment: I ran the exact same thing that I have here on my own machine and it worked. do you get an error or just incorrect answer?

Comment: No error , it just wont convert still format yyyymmdd

Comment: can you put a screenshot of your query and the result here, that might help.

Comment: how to insert image?

Comment: edit your original question and you should have an option to do so otherwise try pastebin or something.